# Can't wrap my head around Preprocessing Macros

Tags: c, macros, conditional-compilation

I'm still struggling with macros in C.

So this one should return -2:

```
#define A
#define C
int main()
{
    int i =
    #ifdef A
    #ifdef B // if A AND B is defined
        -1
    #else    // A is defined AND B is NOT defined
        -2
    #endif
    #else   // A is not defined
        -3
    #endif
    ;
    printf("%d \n", i);
}
```

why isthis returning -3 then:

```
#define B
#define C
int main()
{
    int i =
    #ifdef A
    #ifdef C
        -1
    #else
        -2
    #endif
    #else
        -3
    #endif
    ;
    printf("%d \n", i);
}
```

It seems to me as if macros have their own logic.

Comment: You define A and C. With `#ifdef A` you can test A is defined.  Or use `#ifndef A`to test if it is not defined. Depending on the result, the code in that part will be compiled for the porgram. This is often used in header files, to prevent declerations or definitions to be done twice.

Comment: 2nd one prints -3 because A is not defined anymore. `#ifdef C` is inside `#ifdef A`so it won't even be tested. And the `#else` of `#ifdef A` is `-3`

Comment: What do you expect and why?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define A
#define C
int main()
{
    int i =
    #ifdef A
    #ifdef B // if A AND B is defined
        -1
    #else    // A is defined AND B is NOT defined
        -2
    #endif
    #else   // A is not defined
        -3
    #endif
    ;
    printf("%d \n", i);
}
```

in your case i will be -2, since A is defined but B is NOT defined

Comment: Thank you. I edited my comment to add your comments, and a nother sample which's confusing me.

Comment: @ranpos  you did not define A, so the last case works in the updated question. think of simple if-else and follow Sourav Ghosh 's answer for identation. then things will be clear IMO.

Answer (score 1):

First let me indent the code accordingly for ease of understanding.

```
#define A
#define C
int main()
{
    int i =
    #ifdef A
        #ifdef B
             -1
        #else
             -2
        #endif
    #else
        -3
    #endif
    ;
    printf("%d \n", i);
}
```

Now, as per the `#ifdef` preprocessing directive, quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.10.1,

> Preprocessing directives of the forms
>
> ```
> # ifdef identifier new-line groupopt<br>
> # ifndef identifier new-line groupopt`<br>
> ```
>
> check whether the identifier is or is not currently defined as a macro name.[...]
>
> Each directive’s condition is checked in order. If it evaluates to false (zero), the group
>   that it controls is skipped: directives are processed only through the name that determines
>   the directive in order to keep track of the level of nested conditionals; the rest of the
>   directives’ preprocessing tokens are ignored, as are the other preprocessing tokens in the
>   group. Only the first group whose control condition evaluates to true (nonzero) is
>   processed. If none of the conditions evaluates to true, and there is a `#else` directive, the
>   group controlled by the `#else` is processed; lacking a `#else` directive, all the groups
>   until the `#endif` are skipped.

In respect to your code,

- `#ifdef A` is TRUE,
- `#ifdef B` is FALSE, so continues to `#else` part, and `-2` is included in the source code.
- skips until outer `#endif`.

So, after preprocessing, the code *essentially* looks like

```
int i =-2 ;
printf("%d \n", i);
```

Check the output, it should be -2.

As per the same logic, you can find out the preprocessed output of the other code.

Answer (score 1):

In first case,

```
int i =
#ifdef A
    #ifdef B // if A AND B is defined
        -1
    #else    // A is defined AND B is NOT defined
        -2
    #endif
#else   // A is not defined
    -3
#endif
```

Here, `A` is defined but `B` is not. So, The last `else` case will be considered only. Hence the output will be `-2`

Whereas, in Second case,

```
int i =
#ifdef A
    #ifdef C
        -1
    #else
        -2
    #endif
#else
    -3
#endif
```

`C` is defined but `A` is not so again it will go to the last `else` condition returning `-3`.

Comment: for the first case, A and C is defined only, output will be -2, not -3.

Comment: @tigris Thanks for pointing out. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer in a plain simple fashion.

Firstly you are right macros do have their own logic and perhaps you understand how they are preprocessors and all. If not, then preprocessors are the first bit of code read by the compiler no matter where in your source code they appear.

After the compiler checks the macros it is possible, like here in your case, that certain part of your normal code becomes "invisible" to the compiler. Now lets analyze how and what becomes hidden or invisible code in your case.

In this case you are using `#define A` and `#define C`. This is similar to Boolean (but not exactly) that A and B have been declared 'true' or 'defined'.

Then with `#ifdef A` (`#ifdef`: is the short form of if defined) there is a if statement here. It checks if A is 'defined' or not. In your case A is defined so we go on to the next part, which can be seen as code within this if statement. If A were not defined here we would go to the second `#else   // A is not defined`.

So now we check `#ifdef B` and no B is not defined in your case so we go to the first `#else    // A is defined AND B is NOT defined` that follows. Hence setting the value of I to -2. The `#endif` is like the closing curly brackets of the second if statement. Next we go to the second `#endif` because A was defined hence we do not go into the second `#else`.

In the end you get the answer as -2. I checked this code and it does return -2.